# Notapad++ column editing: how to deselect a clicked location?

Tags: notepad++, text-editing, editing, selection, mouse-click

1- There is an option in NP++ to hold Ctrl while clicking in multiple locations in the text file, so the cursor stays there for multi-editing.  I want to know how to de-select a clicked location?

I tried clicking with alt, or shift but they don't work.

2- Also, is there a way to auto put the cursor on a specific character in all the document? Without having to click on each one while holding Ctrl?

Example: searching for the word "Ipsum" for example puts the cursor at the end of the word or whatever:

[image]

Comment: For the first question, I'm afraid there are no ways to do that.

Comment: For the second one, it is not clear what you really want to do. Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1377118/edit) and add an example. May be you could do it with Find/Replace using regex.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I added an example that explains: searching for a certain word or even a symbol like a period "." or something, puts the cursor in all the results.

Comment: You could do: Find `Ipsum`, Replace `what you want`. This will act as multi-editing.

Comment: I don't want to replace, I want to put the cursor next or before that word

Comment: OK, but what for? Is it for editing? What do you want to do after positionning the cursor? I thing you have an XY problem, see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: What I want to do after putting the cursor in multiple places is use "column editing" to add numbers list: 1,2,3,4,5 respectively in the locations of the cursor. Or any other list through the "Edit > Column Editor"

Comment: OK, I see. I don't think it is possible. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: Here is a perl oneliner that does the job: `perl -ane 'while(/\bIpsum\b/g){$i++;s/\bIpsum\b/$&$i/};print' file`

Comment: So I installed Perl in windows as this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joMHrFJITOs - how do I run that script that you send and make it work in the existing file with the text?

Comment: See my  answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have installed Perl, you can run any script in command line like this:

```
perl path/to/script.pl
```

or, for a oneliner:

```
perl -e 'the instruction' path\to\inputfile > path\to\outputfile
```

In your case, you have to read a file and write the result in an another file:

```
perl -ane "while(/\bIpsum\b/g){$i++;s/\bIpsum\b/$&$i/};print" inputfile > outputfile
```

If you want to to the replace inplace (i.e. replace the file):

```
perl -i.back -ane "while(/\bIpsum\b/g){$i++;s/\bIpsum\b/$&$i/};print" inputfile
```

This will backup `original` file in `original.back`
**DON'T RUN TWICE** without revert the original file.

You'll find useful information at [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)